# Javascript Searching and Filter items

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have this...

```
var subc=[
    { r: 'aaa', d: 'ddda'},
    { r: 'bbb', d: 'dddc'},
    { r: 'ccc', d: 'dddc'},
    { r: 'ddd', d: 'dddd'}
]

var mat=[{
    value1: 'xxxx'
    value2: 'yyyy'
    value3: 'zzzz'
    matSubc: ['aaa','ccc']
}]
```

and i want to filter subc from the values of mat.matSubc to obtain the Result

```
result=[ 
    { r: 'aaa', d: 'ddda'}, 
    { r: 'ccc', d: 'dddc'} 
]
```

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = subc.filter(function(v){
    return mat[0].matSubc.indexOf(v.r) >= 0;
});
```

This uses the `.filter()` method to check each object in the `subc` array for its `r` key inside of the `matSubc` array. If it exists, it returns the entire object.